# Making a method that makes a string CamelCase

Tags: ruby

I am trying to work through this problem.

Add a method named add_index to the Array class. The method should take the index value of an element's position and add it to the String in the same position.

Hint: the each_with_index method should help you solve this problem. Try to find the each_with_index method yourself in Ruby Docs, and learn how it's used.

Here is my current code:  **I am not creating the full class or using self, I am just testing how self would act with the variable a.  In the test, self is pass "This is a test".

```
new-host:~$ irb
2.0.0p247 :001 > a = "This is a test"
 => "This is a test" 
2.0.0p247 :002 > a.split.join.downcase
 => "thisisatest" 
2.0.0p247 :003 > a.split
 => ["This", "is", "a", "test"] 
    #Should I do something with the array first? I could pass them into a code block to call the .capitalize method on them...with this in mind I am not sure how to skp the [0] of the array.
2.0.0p247 :004 > a.split.join.downcase[0..3]
 => "this" 

2.0.0p247 :005 > a.split.join.downcase.capitalize
 => "Thisisatest"
```

Ultimately I need the "This is a test" to look like "thisIsATest".  I've been trying to figure this out for a while now.  If anyone could give some insight I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

One idea I have is to do something like this:

```
a.split.each do |num| num.to_s.downcase
2.0.0p247 :010?>   end
#I know this isn't right but from the syntax I know I think doing something like this is a step in the right direction.
```

"This is a test" is what's being run through the test:

```
describe "String" do
  describe "camel_case" do
    it "leaves first word lowercase" do
      "test".camel_case.should eq("test")
    end
    it "should lowercase first letter if it isn't" do
      "Test".camel_case.should eq("test")
    end
    it "should combine words using camel case" do
      "This is a test".camel_case.should eq("thisIsATest")
    end
  end
end
```

I am excluding the class String and def camel_case for my method.  I am just trying to test the block of code for my method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def camel_case(str)
  str.downcase.split.each_with_index.map { |v,i|  i == 0 ? v : v.capitalize }.join
end
```

**OR**

```
def camel_case(str)
  words = str.downcase.split
  words.shift + words.map(&:capitalize).join
end

puts camel_case('This is a test')
```

**output**

```
thisIsATest
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved camelcase problem

```
a = "This is a test"
a.split.map(&:capitalize}.join
"ThisIsATest"
```

#### Update

```
a.split.each_with_index.map { |i, el| (i.capitalize unless el.eql? 0) || i.downcase}.join
```

or

```
str = "This is a test".split
str[0].downcase + str[1..-1].map(&:capitalize).join
```

Comment: From the OP: `Ultimately I need the "This is a test" to look like "thisIsATest".` - he doesn't want the first letter capitalised.

Comment: How would I single out the first word so it is all lowercase? I assume I have to add a .downcase somewhere on "this".  Thanks for the first part. I haven't used map at all, looking it up now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`a.split.map(&:capitalize).join`

@edit: With  gsub

`a.gsub(/ \w+/) { |w| w.strip.capitalize }.gsub(/^\w/) {|w| w.downcase }`

Comment: Almost, I just need the first word to be all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way...

```
s_original = "This is a test"
s_converted = ""
s_original.downcase.split(" ").each_with_index {|word, i| s_converted = "#{s_converted}#{if i > 0 then word.capitalize! else word end}"}

puts s_original #=> "This is a test"
puts s_converted #=> "thisIsATest"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `each_with_index` to distinguish between the first word and the rest. Something like:

```
"This is a test".split.each_with_index.map { |word, index|
  if index == 0
     # transform first word
  else
     # transform other words
  end
}.join
```

The first transformation could be `word.downcase`, the other `word.capitalize`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

`a = "This is a test".split.map!(&:capitalize).join.sub!(/^\w{1}/) { |first| first.downcase }`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it:

```
def camel_case(str)
    ary = str.split
    ary[0].downcase + ary[1..-1].map(&:capitalize).join
end
```

[example](http://ideone.com/W4C6Ht) usage:

```
camel_case "This is a test"
# => "thisIsATest"
```

Reference:

- [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split)
- [String#downcase](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-downcase)
- [String#capitalize](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize)
- [Array#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D)
- [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map)
- [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-join)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way:

```
"This is a test".tr(' ','_').camelize(:lower)
# "thisIsATest"
```